# Did any country ever implement a minimum salary for public school teachers?

Tags: international, education, public-sector-compensation, minimum-wage

> Sen. Bernie Sanders (I-Vt.) called for a minimum salary of $60,000 for
> public school teachers, capitalizing on the push by President Biden in
> his State of the Union speech to give public school teachers a raise.
>
> “We should be paying public school teachers a minimum of at least
> $60,000 a year,” Sanders said at a town hall at the Capitol on Monday
> night with national teachers union leaders. “I am proud to tell you I
> will soon be introducing legislation to do just that.”
>
> Sanders’s call for a minimum salary for public school teachers comes
> after Biden made a pitch for a number of education policies during his
> State of the Union, including providing increased access to preschool
> and giving teachers a raise.

https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/3857907-sanders-calls-for-minimum-salary-of-60000-for-public-school-teachers/

Did any country ever implement a minimum salary for public school teachers? I was reading an article about a proposal from Bernie Sanders of instituting a minimum salary for public school teachers in the U.S. and I was wondering if any country decided to institute a minimum salary for public school teachers specifically, because upon research I couldn't find any information on this.

Comment: Note that the issue is not as clear as might be expected from Sanders (surprise!).  *Average* US teacher salaries aren't that bad, whatever the absence of regulation says.  https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/teacher-salary-by-country  I also wonder how Sanders is going to police states' teacher salaries, unless the Feds pay them.  Not directly an answer but I think Finland for one has a policy to make teaching an attractive, and competitive, profession.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first clear-cut example I came across that is readily comparable to what Sanders has proposed is the national wage floor for teachers that went into effect [in 2009 in Brazil](https://www.ei-ie.org/en/item/17401:brazilian-teachers-win-national-standard-professional-wage-scale).

However the question is vague and assumes that national political/educational systems are all comparable to that of the United States. [A report on teacher salaries in the EU](https://eurydice.eacea.ec.europa.eu/media/2830/download) provides specific figures for "the statutory salaries of full-time, fully qualified beginning teachers with the minimum qualification to enter the teaching profession". While the precise details of the legal framework in each country is not clear to me, this implies that something like a national minimum wage for teachers may effectively be the norm across Europe.

Comment: That is correct. In most countries in the European Union, teacher salaries are either subject to minimum requirements set by the state, or the result of collective bargaining where the lowest pay of a fully qualified teacher constitutes the _de facto_ minimum salary.

Answer (score 21):

This is a situation where the US is the exception not only compared to Western Europe but also compared to most of the rest of the world. Public school teachers are government employees as the name suggest, so their salary is entirely in control of the government. The difference is mostly in which level of the government is responsible for it.

What is special about the US is that large parts how schools are governed is at a very local level of the government and this includes salaries. In the US every little town has their own rules on how public school teachers are paid and these rules and salaries vary significantly across the country. This is not the case in almost any other country. Salaries for public school teachers are generally determined at the federal level or at the level of states.

So just by construction for most countries the idea that the federal government imposes some absolute minimum for public school teachers doesn't make much sense, either it determines the full salary scale itself or at most it can talk to the handful of states and check what they are doing.

Comment: They also vary significantly within a single US state.  There are wide variations and one school district might pay 10 or 15 percent more than the next town over

Comment: @nuggethead in principle there can be good reasons for that if there’s a significant gradient in cost of living. In general statutory salary frameworks having a geographic component certainly isn’t unheard of, even if set at a national level.

Comment: @origimbo: And it is always important to remember scale. E.g., Germany, the largest country in the EU, is half the size of Texas, so a federal standard in Germany would be roughly equivalent to a regional standard in Texas. The entire EU, consisting of 27 countries, many of which federations of a dozen states, is half the size of the US.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are comparing by land area, the much more useful comparision here is by population. Then Germany is around 3 times the size of Texas and the EU is roughly 1.5 times the US. Canada, which has slightly bigger area then the US doesn't have different teacher salaries in every village either.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Public school teachers are not employed by the United States.  They are employed by individual states, and in some states by municipal governments.  I think even Washington DC public school teachers are employed by the municipal government.  Even the President of the United States cannot fire state-employed school teachers.  State governments are not "lower levels" of the US government. They have substantial sovereignty.

Comment: @wrod Public school teachers are employed by 'the government'. The second sentence makes clear that this does not refer solely to the top level of government but rather to all levels of government combined. What kind of hierarchy or mutual sovereignity the different levels of government have is irrelevant for that. State level and municipal governments in the US are part of the governing structure and hence part of the government. This does not imply that they are subsidaries of the federal government.

Comment: @quarague it's not irrelevant.  it goes to the heart of the question.  The Fed govt can't set salary levels of any state employees.  They can't set salary levels of state police, either.  Teachers also have very different education and licensing requirements in different states. "Lower level" creates an impression that there is a hierarchy.  But that's not the case.  The President can't fire a governor.  He can't can't even fire a state teacher or a state policeman.  There is a separation of powers between states and the feds.  And teachers don't work for the feds.

Comment: @quarague simply calling it "lower level" creates an impression for people from other countries (without federalism) that state governments are within the hierarchy of the federal government.  But they are not.

Comment: @wrod I don't think the word 'level' implies a hierarchy of power but apparently you do. Do you have a better suggestion on how to refer to the different 'levels of government' federal/ state/ municipal?

Comment: @quarague no, what I "apparently" think is that not everyone will read this answer the way you meant for it to sound.  You may take federalism as an inherent feature of a government.  But it's actually pretty rare.  And most people, from around the world, need to be explained that this kind of thing can even be possible.  Without federalism, these decisions being made locally sounds like an arbitrary delegation.

Comment: This answer could be somewhat improved by mentioning that local school budgets in the US are typically funded by local property taxes.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't *exactly* what you're asking, but while the US itself doesn't set a minimum salary, individual states may do so.

For example, [Texas](https://tea.texas.gov/texas-educators/salary-and-service-record/minimum-salary-schedule/2023-2024-minimum-salary-schedule) sets the minimum salary for public school teachers at $33,660/year (for the standard 10 month contract), and the minimum figure goes up as teachers get more experience.

That said, while the state sets a *minimum* salary, actual salaries are typically set by the school districts themselves, and most districts pay more -- but some do pay the minimum.